# SVG Animation: анимировать дугу, как она нарисована

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Я рисую `Arc` с `SVG`, используя следующий фрагмент:

https://jsfiddle.net/e6dx9oza/293/

Начальный и конечный углы дуги будут динамически перемещаться, когда вызывается метод `describeArc`  для вычисления пути.

Кто-нибудь знает, как я могу анимировать дугу, когда она нарисована? В принципе, я хочу, чтобы дуга была плавно прорисована с задержкой, вместо того, чтобы ее рисовать за один раз, как в данном случае.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49654966/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос  не описываете точно, что вы подразумеваете под «анимацией».

Я собираюсь предположить, что вы хотите, чтобы сектор открывался до конечного положения.

Вот один из способов сделать это.

```html
<style>
svg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
</style> 
<svg>
  <path id="arc1" fill="green" />
</svg>

<script>
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = [
        "M", start.x, start.y, 
        "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y,
        "L", x,y,
        "L", start.x, start.y
    ].join(" ");
    
    //console.log(d);

    return d;       
}


function animateSector(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, animationDuration) {

   var startTime = performance.now();

   function doAnimationStep() {
     // Get progress of animation (0 -> 1)
     var progress = Math.min((performance.now() - startTime) / animationDuration, 1.0);
     // Calculate the end angle for this point in the animation
     var angle = startAngle + progress * (endAngle - startAngle);
     // Calculate the sector shape
     var arc = describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, angle);
     // Update the path
     document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", arc);
     // If animation is not finished, then ask browser for another animation frame.
     if (progress < 1.0)
       requestAnimationFrame(doAnimationStep);
   }

   requestAnimationFrame(doAnimationStep);
}

animateSector(100, 100, 100, 120, 418.25, 1000); 
</script>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e6dx9oza/351/

Comment: на мой взгляд - если ещё сделаете вариант с тем что эта штуковина будет как будто съедать что то то будет ваще жесть

Comment: @МаксимЛенский как paceman? Но это совсем другая анимация - две створки замкнуты, открываются на этот угол и снова закрываются :)

Comment: что такое paceman ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Ну вот например https://codepen.io/zachary_price/pen/yOqPeN и на  нашем сайте даже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770487/28748

Comment: на css я знаю как ..